# ¿Cómo traducir al español la palabra inglesa "cantankerous"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, español-neutral

Hoy en un blog sobre tecnología me topé con la palabra [*cantankerous*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cantankerous), con la cual se adjetiva a alguien como malhumorado, discutidor y poco cooperativo.

Según el Diccionario Oxford

> [cantankerous](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cantankerous)
>   Bad-tempered, argumentative, and uncooperative.

De inmediato pensé en el americanismo

> [rasquincho](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=rasquincho) 
>   I.    1.  sust/adj. Bo, Ar:NO. Persona que se irrita o enoja con facilidad.

que —en la región al norte de Argentina de donde provengo— se usa certeramente para nombrar a quien es así.

Mi pregunta es **¿qué otra palabra en español neutro tiene el significado y connotaciones de cantankerous?** Adicionalmente me gustaría saber: ¿Qué otras palabras existen en los argots regionales, como sinónimos de **rasquincho**?

Comment: Una definición posible que se me ocurre es "cascarrabias"

Comment: *Antes que lleguemos a la casa de mi abuelo, tengo que decirte, es un poco ... especial.* // Quisquilloso.

Comment: Quizás "gruñón" -- https://dle.rae.es/gru%C3%B1%C3%B3n

Comment: Ahora me inclino por *malhumorado, enojón.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abro una respuesta colectiva para que muchos podamos aportar enriqueciendo el conocimiento de las versiones regionales conocidas al designar a alguien "que se enfada con facilidad"

- malhumorado / irasible / enojón (general)
- chinchudo (Argentina / Bolivia / Paraguay / Uruguay)

> [chinchudo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chinchudo), -a.
> I.  1.  adj/sust. Bo, Py, Ar, Ur. pop + cult → espon. Referido a persona, que se enoja o irrita con facilidad.
> 2.  adj. Py pop; Ar, pop + cult → espon. Enfadado, de mal humor.

- rascarrabias (Méjico / Guatemala /  Nicaragua / Costa Rica / Ecuador / Bolivia)

> [rascarrabias](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=rascarrabias).
> I.  1.  sust/adj. Mx, Gu, Ni, CR; m-f. Ec, p.u; m-f. Bo. Cascarrabias, persona que se enfada o riñe a menudo. pop + cult → espon.

- cascarrabias (Argentina)
- rasquincho (Argentina, NOA / Bolivia)

> [rasquincho](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=rasquincho)
> I. 1. sust/adj. Bo, Ar:NO. Persona que se irrita o enoja con facilidad.

- mañoso (Chile)

Answer (score 4):

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/cantankerous.html) tiene algunos ejemplos, como "pendenciero", "malhumorado" e "irascible", a los cuales yo agregaría simplemente "mañoso", que en el sur de [Chile](http://palabradechile.blogspot.com/2013/02/manoso.html?m=1) tiene un sentido muy parecido.
*Cantankerous* es peculiarmente anglo en origen, según [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cantankerous)

Comment: Bueno, si esta palabra funciona en Chile, bien.  Pero en México  "mañoso" sería muy diferente de *enojón*....

Comment: Claro, cabe sólo en los "argots regionales". ¿Y en México, significa "hábil o diestro"? ¿O tiene otro significado más siniestro?

Comment: *Mañoso* es para alguien que te juega un truco o albur, o manipulador.  No tengo mucha facilidad de hacer definiciones, perdón.  Eso no es tan preciso como me hubiera gustado.

Comment: Pues, me parece más bien que ustedes lo usan como "astuto" pero con una connotación de "abusivo" o sexual como en el Perú, ¿no? ¡¡Muchas gracias, porque me has salvado de un paso falso algún día!!

Comment: Ay, *astuto* no es igual -- perdón, no se me ocurre una mejor explicación ahorita.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Spanish.SE! Según he visto en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/ma%C3%B1oso?m=form), "mañoso" puede tener diferentes significados dependiendo del país. En todo caso, no creo que tu propuesta corresponda a español neutro, como pedía el OP. Para mí (España), una persona mañosa es una persona habilidosa.

Comment: Sí, es cierto que no es "español neutro". Si no es mucho preguntar, ¿debo editar para aclarar que es solamente una respuesta parcial?

Comment: @ConradoGoodwin la respuesta está bien, aunque la primera parte "Linguee tiene algunos ejemplos" se podría mejorar diciendo cuál(es) de esos ejemplos te parecen adecuados. En general, poner solo un enlace sin contexto no es buena idea, porque el contenido del enlace puede cambiar o desaparecer ([más información en Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)). Pero la parte de "mañoso" es interesante. Bienvenido/a al sitio!